# If I create a C# desktop application with SQLite, will the database get bundled with the installer?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to make an application for managing a small store, which will be offline. I am considering using SQLite for my data handling needs. Once I create the installer for this project, does the database get attached to the installer or will have have to take additional steps to make the application work.

Also is SQLite the best way to approach this or should I consider something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQLite needs a file to work with you can include a file which contains empty schema of your SQLite database in your setup project and copy it to working directory. Or add your empty db file as a resource to your application. And in your connection string builder/provider check existence of the file if it doesn't exists read it from resource and copy to the target location. And also SQLite is good option for that kind of usage.